# Gaussian Elimination modulo 3 without fractions

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

Gaussian elimination can be used to solve a system of linear equations modulo a prime p.

$p=2$ is trivial because no division is ever needed (only $\oplus$ operations).

However, for $p=3$ it seems that I require fractions. For example:

$2X + 2Y + Z = 1 ≡ 3$

To have row reduced form I need the coefficient next to X to be equal to 1. If I divide by 2, then the value on the right becomes 1/2.

Am I missing a simpler way?

Comment: Now I'm thinking I might be able to multiply by 2, since 2*2 = 4 and (4 = 1 ≡ 3). Can anyone confirm this idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any field, division by $x$ is the same as multiplication by $x^{-1}$.  The integers modulo prime $p$ form a field.

Comment: Thank you. Is it the same subtracting the coefficients? For example when subtracting two equations I'd say 1X - 2X = 2X ≡ 3 because 1 - 2 = 2 ≡ 3 .

Comment: First of all, $\equiv 3$ is incorrect notation, if you mean $\mod 3$.  Yes, you do the same arithmetic mod $3$ on the coefficients.